# Find the least positive integer such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i)\ge 123456$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{*}_{+}$ be a function defined as follows: We write $n=2^{a}(2b+1)$ where $a,b$ are non-negative integers in this way,
$$f(n)=f(2^{a}(2b+1))=a^{2}+a+1$$
Determine the least positive integer $n$ such that 
$$f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(n) \ge 123456.$$

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know, for instance, what pattern that $a$ follows for $n=1,2,3,4,\cdots$?

Comment: Interesting.  $f($odd$)=1$, if $2$ divides $n$ but $4$ does not then $f(n)=3$.  Are you supposed to do this on paper or is this going to require a script of some sort?  Because it would be very easy to write a program to solve this.

Comment: Here is another interpretation of the sum: $$f(1)+\cdots+f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty2^i\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^i}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: I think with a program it is very easy. I think a analytic solution would be better.

Comment: @Arthur Your formula fails at $n=8$ and from that point on.

Comment: @IvanNeretin You're right, I hadn't calculated things correctly. This is a corrected one.
$$
f(1) + \cdots + f(n) = n + \sum_{i = 1}^\infty2i\left\lfloor\frac n{2^i}\right\rfloor
$$Every number $\leq n$ is worth $1$. In addition, every even number is worth $2$. In addition to that, every number divisible by $4$ contributes an additional $4$. And then (this is where I was mistaken in my previous comment) every number that is divisible by $8$ contributes $6$ (this follows the even numbers, I was convinced it followed powers of $2$ earlier due to too much christmas on my mind, and being tired).

Comment: This one looks right to me. Also, it is now clear that for large n, $f(1) + \cdots + f(n)\approx5n$, hence $123456/5$ would be a decent approximation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an analytic solution, but it’s a significant step towards one, and it reduces the trial and error to something manageable by hand with a little work. Since it’s not a full solution, however, I’ll just outline it.

First let $a_n=f(2^n)$ for $n\ge 0$; then $a_0=1$, and it’s not hard to verify that $a_n=2a_{n-1}+2n$ for $n\ge 1$. This recurrence can be solved by any standard method to yield

$$a_n=5\cdot2^n-2n-4\;.$$

The next step is to show that if $n=\sum_{k=0}^mb_k2^k$, where each $b_k\in\{0,1\}$, then

$$\begin{align*}
f(n)&=\sum_{k=0}^mb_kf(2^k)=\sum_{k=0}^mb_ka_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^mb_k\left(5\cdot 2^k-2k-4\right)\\
&=5n-2\sum_{k=0}^mb_k(k+2)\;.
\end{align*}$$

It’s also easily checked that $f$ is monotone strictly increasing, and that $f(2n+1)=f(2n)+1$ for $n\ge 1$. Thus, $f(n)\ge\ell$ implies that $5n>\ell$ and hence that $n\ge\left\lceil\frac{\ell}5\right\rceil$.

In fact we can do a bit better. Let $m=\lfloor\lg n\rfloor$; then

$$f(n)\le 5n-2m-4\;,$$

so $f(n)\ge\ell$ requires at a minimum that

$$5n\ge\ell+2(m+2)\;.$$

We want $\ell$ to be a bit less than $5n$, so $\lg\ell$ should be around $m+2$, and a first approximation to $n$ is $\frac{\ell+2\lg\ell}5$. Since in our case $\ell=123456$ is approximately $123\cdot2^{10}$, it’s easy enough to check that $$2^{16}<123456<2^{17}\;,$$ so a first approximation is $n=24698$.

The usual algorithm of repeated division by $2$ shows that $24698=(110000001111010)_{\text{two}}$ and hence that

$$f(24698)=5\cdot24698-2(16+15+8+7+6+5+3)=123490-120=123370\;.$$

This is too small by $86$. Replacing the block $01111$ with $10000$ to get $(110000010000010)_{\text{two}}$ would increase $n$ by $8$ and hence $5n$ by $40$, while also subtracting $2\cdot9$ from and adding $2(8+7+6+5)$ to $f(n)$:

$$f(24706)=123370+40-18+52=123444\;,$$

which is only $12$ short. We noted above that increasing $n$ to $24707$ only adds $1$ to $f(n)$, and it’s not hard to see that increasing it to $24708$ isn’t quite good enough: we get an increase of $10$ from the $5n$ term, but we lose $2$ from term that depends on the location of the one bits, so $f(24708)=123452$. From this we know that $f(24709)=123453$, and it’s clearly worth calculating

$$f(24710)=f((110000010000110)_{\text{two}})=123550-2(16+15+9+4+3)=123456\;.$$